# Make a second drop down required if the first drop down matches a specific value?

Tags: excel, list, if-statement, excel-2010, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a column that in every cell there is a expanded list of names.
If a certain value, for example,

> Mario

is selected from the list, then require entry of the values available in the drop down in the second column. If a different value is in the first drop down, then the second drop down is not required.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do... Could you try to clarify what should happen?

Comment: well, i have a cell with a list of names. Only if the name selected is for example `Mario` then the second cell (B1) becomes required. Although not. Right?

Comment: You could use conditional formatting to color the appropriate cells red if `Mario` was selected and the required cell is blank.  This would help indicate that there is information missing.

Comment: @David_D Er... I'm afraid it's still not so clear :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use data validation. In B1, choose data validation, make **Allow:** a List, and put a formula in **Source:** that fits your needs.

For example, this formula would allow only a value that you put in column C to be chosen if "Mario" is in A1. Otherwise you can only choose a value in column D.

```
=IF(A1="Mario",C:C,D:D)
```

This allows control of your second drop-down.